# Запросы GET на страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Объясните пожалуйста ,как сделать запрос на страницу ,и получить доступ к DOM-дереву и к самим элементам . Например я хочу с yotube выгрузить название видео , и вставить на свою страницу .Желательно примеры

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать парсер на php. Библиотека html dom parser. Есть документация http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/